# elements of array of C-defined structures have incomplete type when compiled as C++

Tags: c++, c, struct

I am trying to embed lua inside C++ programm. It works well until I try to implement interfaces. 
Typically, at some point an array of structures is introduced to map names inside lua to functions defined in C.
The structure is typedef is done in the lauxlib.h, which is written in C. I believe my writings could be qualified as C++.

I need the array of structures of this type in order to pass it to an auxiliary function, that handles the C-Lua interaction.
I wish to keep them inside separate namespace if possible.
I need the programm to be compiled by g++ with a following command:
`g++ -std=c++14 -static -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-strict-aliasing -D_LINUX -lm -s -x c++ -O2 -Wall -Wtype-limits -Wno-unknown-pragmas -o $name $files`

During compilation I get the following error:

```
In file included from MyInterfaceWrappers.h:3:0,
                 from MyInterface.h:12,
                 from MyInterface.cpp:1: MyInterfacePlayer.h:32:2: error: elements of array ‘const MyInterfaceWrappers::luaL_reg
MyInterfaceWrappers::MyMetamethods []’ have incomplete type   };
```

Here are contents of the file that is referenced by the error message (they are slightly trimmed but it is the const struct inside namespace that is pointed to by message):

```
extern "C"{
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}

static int getId (lua_State *L);
static int isMe (lua_State *L);

namespace MyInterfaceWrappers {
    const struct luaL_reg MyMetamethods [] = {
        {"getId",getId},
        {"isMe",isMe},
        {NULL,NULL}
    };
};
```

How can this be fixed? Can this be fixed without altering the C sources?

Comment: Using `const struct luaL_reg` tells the compiler "the type is `luaL_reg` and trust me that it's a `struct`". Leaving out the `struct` would produce a compilation error indicating that the type doesn't exist, which would have allowed you to detect the typo.

Comment: This is not a "simple" typo but a systematic one which easily crawls in when in transition from C to C++. Please keep it open.

Comment: @JensGustedt The typo is misspelling `luaL_Reg`. I wouldn't vote to close as typo as the question has a lot going for it beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled `luaL_Reg` as `luaL_reg`. And since you used an elaborated type specifier (`struct luaL_reg` or the equivalent `class luaL_reg`) it's as though you introduced a declaration for the `luaL_reg` class type. That type is incomplete naturally.

So fix the spelling, and don't use an elaborated type specifier, C++ doesn't force you to.

Comment: I retracted my comment as I had missed the part where you specify what you meant by elaborated type specifier on my first read through.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - It was a good comment actually. I feel it made me improve the answer still

Comment: The OP obviously comes from C, and there the `struct` is mandatory unless you do some special `typedef`. So this is a translation error for a place where the two languages disagree.

Comment: @JensGustedt - The misspelled structure tag will cause the same sort of error in C as well (or the equivalent thereof, if the error text must differ). The translation is not the cause of the error. It just would have given a different error, that perhaps would have been clearer to the OP.